# How do I set default Python in Windows

Tags: python

I have searched many answers on StackOverflow, but I don't seem to find exactly what I want. I have just installed `Python 3.7` and when I run the command `C:\Users\Dell>python` I get this:

> ```
> Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> ```

I know it has something to do with Anaconda. But, I don't know exactly what's wrong.

***Question***

I expected to see something like `Python 3.7.0`. Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong and how should I change this to what I want? What I should do to get `Python 3.7` by default?

Comment: Check windows environment variables for PYTHONPATH and PATH.  You never know there are other process also install a different version of python and set the path.  If you have sufficient resources, it is recommended to use VM with ubuntu/linux.

Comment: @mootmoot: `PYTHONPATH` should be irrelevant (it's for adding additional user specified module import locations, Python itself doesn't set it or install anything to it). Only `PATH` matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is: Don't run `python`. Run [`py`, the Python launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows). By default, it runs the latest installed version of Python. If you want a specific version, you can follow it with a switch, e.g. `py -2` for latest Python 2, `py -3.6` for 3.6, etc.

Yes, you could go mucking about with your `PATH` environment variable settings to try putting the Python 3.7 install folder ahead of 3.6, but then you just have the same problem again a few months from now when you install 3.8. The launcher was created precisely because of the difficulty of managing side-by-side Python installations on Windows, and solves all of these problems seamlessly (plus, it's four fewer characters to type if all you want is the latest installed version!).

Note that for consistency, you basically never want to launch other utilities by name, instead using the `py` launcher and the `-m` switch to make sure you're launching the tool associated with the version you expect. So for example, instead of running `pip ...args...`, run `py -mpip ...args...`, which ensures you run the `pip` corresponding to the Python launcher's default Python version.

Comment: Thanks! this helped! Also, which python version is used to run a python script by default? if I run a script named `python abcxyz.py` does it run in the latest version?

Comment: @Satya: That's actually the best part about the launcher. If you put in a UNIX-style shebang line in a standard form, [the `py.exe` launcher will parse it and do The Right Thing™](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/#shebang-line-parsing), e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env python3` will launch the script with the latest 3.x Python installed. If, when you installed Python, the `py.exe` launcher was registered as the handler for the `.py` extension (the installer offers this option), you don't even need to type `py`; just running `abcxyz.py` will work. Makes it possible to write fully portable scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have your python 3.7 version in your path variable higher than that 3.6 version.